# Is there any way to increase a rubber-bands lifetime?

Tags: material-science, elasticity

Rubber-bands are simple, yet very useful. Old rubber bands(5 years?) get brittle? Why is that?

Comment: Here is an interesting fact: In "Surely You are Joking Mr.Feynman", Feynman talks about how he used to fix old typewriters using rubber bands when he was a kid. When he moved into California, the trick did not work as the humidity levels were different (he was in NY when he was a kid).

Comment: I do not know what kind of rubber bands Feynman used, but I know that humidity is not the factor which made his repair short-lived in California. Rubber life depends on light, temperature, color, ozone and in extreme cases on some kinds of photochemical smog.

Comment: How inclusive of this group to allow and answer a chemistry and engineering failure question! ;-)

Comment: I think the issue is that rubber bands are made of natural rubber and nobody engineered them to last. I bought some that are made of EPDM (synthetic rubber) so I'll let you know in 5 years how that worked out :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a rubber band is usable for 5 years, it's a very good one.

There is not much you can do to prevent brittleness other than storing them in a dark and cool place. Light and oxygen are the most dangerous enemy of rubber.

The biggest influence on lifespan is the manufacturer, because they can choose 
to use a persistent (expensive) type of rubber (eg Kalrez®, ask for prizes!)
Of course there are less extreme rubbers in prize.

Another way to extend life is to change the color; adding carbon black prolonges the life of rubber substantially (Protection from light) and by adding antioxidants.

The background of embrittlement of polybutadiene (polyisoprene) based 
rubbers is crosslinking by radical chain reactions with oxygen. 
Cheap urethane rubbers die from similar reactions, but those usually 
become sticky, even liquid by this processes.